# disable viewgit download option

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, git

I installed the web browsing interface viewgit on my server,  in order to
manage my git repositories. Everything works pretty well, but I bothered by the
download option of every file.

Is there a possibility to disable the download option for some files
or projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the possibility of a .htaccess file in the viewgit directory.
You can use this to save every directory.
If you call your viewgit site then, a popup for a username and a password will
appear.
This information are defined in the .htaccess and .htpasswd file